# How to make a jUnit4 test case class Spring Test case class?

Tags: hibernate, spring, junit4

I have a jUnit4 test case class ( extends TestCase). I am testing some code having Spring D.I and Hibernate.  Somehow when i execute test ,looks like  some internal transactions are rolling my test changes back. I am deleting a record using HibernateTemplate but nothing is getting deleted in database. I got a suggestion to make my test case transactional by making my class a Spring test class( using Spring Test Runner ) and use @Transactional attribute before method call.  Can somebody please tell how can i make my Junit4 test class Spring test class? What configs do I need  and which class to extend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it "extends TestCase", it's a JUnit 3.x test class. JUnit 4.x classes don't need to inherit from anything, they use @Test annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend [`AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.html) or add these annotations to your test class:

```
@TestExecutionListeners(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class)
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests which is already configured for transaction support.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests`. I highly recommend detailed reading of [Testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html) chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Everything about Spring testing is thoroughly explained in reference [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).

The phenomenon you are experiencing is due the fact that Spring automatically wraps test methods in rollback-only transactions when test-case class is annotated with `@Transactional`. This has certain benefits: you won't corrupt your database during the test and each test works on the same data, so you are not introducing inter-test dependencies.